# Enable New Line in Textarea - Jquery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using **append** function. Function is working fine. Everything is ok.

But when is press some **ENTERS (Break Line)** in Textarea. It appears in the form of New Lines in Textarea but when it appends to HTML it doesnt appears in the Form of New Lines.

Take a Quick Look at this Image:

[image]

**Here is my DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/YRKxR/17/

Here is my Jquery Code Or you can simply visit my JsFiddle DEMO:

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        $(".append_data").append('<tr><td>'+description+'</td></tr>');
                     });
```

Comment: A newline is not a <br />. Try to convert it

Comment: _“but when it appends to HTML it doesnt appears in the Form of New Lines”_ – of course not, because HTML does not “display newlines” under normal circumstances (anybody with basic HTML knowledge should know that). So either append them to an element that _does_ display them (f.e. `<pre>`), or format the element you are appending to accordingly with CSS (`white-space` property) – or replace the newlines with `<br>`.

Comment: @CBroe Will you please update my JsFiddle and help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRy this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/YRKxR/18/

white-space :pre is required

```
$('.add_more').click(function()
                     {
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                         $(".append_data").append('<tr><td style="white-space:pre;">'+description+'</td></tr>');
                     });
```

Comment: I havent downrated. Question was good as many times we forget about white-space attribute.